# Are these plants Aloe or Gasteraloe?

Tags: identification, indoors, container-gardening, aloe

I have received these plants from somebody who didn't know what their name was. Can you help with an ID?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do look very much like *[Gasteraloe beguinii](http://worldofsucculents.com/gasteraloe-beguinii-lizard-tail/)*